# Como autocompletar datos de una fila especifica con jquery

Tags: autocompletar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimados los datos que estan por default vienen de una base de datos, sin embargo quisiera que al momento de recargar quisiera que adicional a los datos por default se carguen solo las filas en las que consta el id del alumno en la tabla que invoca.
Ya que los datos vendran de otra tabla. 
Quisiera saber si me pueden dar alguna idea de como realizarlo.

Comment: Necesitas poner tu codigo, de otra manera es muy dificil ayudarte.

Comment: te sugiero leer : https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask